# Upgrade Python patch version from 3.8.10 to 3.8.16 on Windows without binary installers

Tags: python

According to the [docs](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3816/), 3.8.10 was the last Python 3.8 version with binary installers. I need to install 3.8.16 on my local system. So I installed 3.8.10 first and then wanted to upgrade.

After unzipping + extracting the tar.gz file from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3816/), I wanted to run the `setup.py` file, but get an error:

```py
PS C:\Users\XXXXXX\Downloads\Python-3.8.16> python .\setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\setup.py", line 2416, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\setup.py", line 2374, in main
    set_compiler_flags('CFLAGS', 'PY_CFLAGS_NODIST')
  File ".\setup.py", line 86, in set_compiler_flags
    sysconfig.get_config_vars()[compiler_flags] = flags + ' ' + py_flags_nodist
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

How can I upgrade the Python version on Windows?

Comment: You don't run the setup.py file to install a new Python version. Please read the readme file included for build instructions; that what it's for. It'll direct you to another readme on how to build Python on Windows.

Comment: Curious: what is the reason to stick to Python 3.8? I could imagine you have a large set of packages that you don't want to reinstall for a later version, but otherwise, more recent Python versions tend to be backward compatible with release 3.8.

Comment: Installing a large set of packages is not a significant issue unless you don't know what packages are installed in the first place, which is a separate problem. Any significant code base should have an explicit list of dependencies (whether in `requirements.txt`, `pyproject.toml`, etc) that can easily be reinstalled on demand in a fresh virtual environment.

Comment: Synapse Spark pools are fixed to Python 3.8 at the moment

Comment: @chepner, I fail to see the connection to my question?

Comment: It's not; it's a response to @9769953. I agree that there are reasons to need an up-to-date Python 3.8 that doesn't involve unwillingness to upgrade to newer versions.

Comment: Ah, understood now

Comment: @chepner I mentioned it, because some people might feel that way. I don't say it's a good thing, I just can imagine people avoiding upgrading for this reason.